# Reduce Mat grouping equal values

Tags: android, opencv3.0

Source one-channel Mat (single row mat):

```
[0,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,0,255]
```

final (desired) one-channel Mat (single row mat):

```
[0,255,0,255,0,255,0,255]
```

Idea is remove duplicate column values and reduce the matrix with out these repeated pixel values, saving only the first occurence.

I have tried Core.reduce function with Core.REDUCE_MAX option but with no result.

Any Ideas?

Thanks, regards.

Comment: You can't do this with OpenCV. You'd better treat the image as an array and make your own function. In C++ there is [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) that does this exactly, probably there is some library function also in Java

Comment: Finally I implement my own function. Thank you.